# Using virtual ICollection with SQLite returns an error

Tags: c#, sqlite, maui

I want to create a simple database with `SQLite` where 2 tables are linked like in Entity Framework. For this reason, I created 2 classes

```
public class Word
{
    public virtual ICollection<WordStatistic> WordStatistics { get; set; }
}

public class WordStatistic
{
    public bool RightAnswer { get; set; }
    public virtual Word Word { get; set; }
    public long WordId { get; set; }
}
```

When the application starts and creates the database

```
var result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<Word>();
result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<WordStatistic>();
```

I get this error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[LanguageInUse.Domain.WordStatistic]'

[image]

So, is it possible to link the tables like that? If I want to get the `Word` with all the related `WordStatistic`, do I have to perform 2 queries? Can I have only one query that returns the total record for `WordStatistic` for each `Word` and also count how many `RightAnswer` there are?

Comment: use [https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions] for FK relations